# Is it possible to split file and append the pieces with same extension in one liner?

Tags: bash, rename, split

I did it in two commands --- one for splitting, and one for moving. I can't seem to find my way around it such as to have it all done with one  line.
What I did was:

```
split.exe --bytes=2300k -d 01_somefile.mp3 01_somefile.mp3
```

to get **01_somefile.mp301, 01_somefile.mp302, 01_somefile.mp303**, and so on. Then

```
for file in *0?; do mv "$file" "$file.mp3"; done
```

to have them all back as mp3.

I would appreciate if someone could help me with an one liner for this that loops through the directory and does this splitting and renaming. I am still poor with the commands. I've tried this:

```
for file in *.MP3; do split.exe --bytes=2500k -d "$file" "$file" && mv "$file" "$file".mp3; done
```

I want to ask how can I control the name of the resulting pieces.
Say, I have this file in the dir: 01_dickens_copperfield.mp3, next to 02.dickens_copperfield.mp3 and so on. I'm still finding them large and want them broken to other pieces and finally, want them renamed as .mp3

Doing

```
for file in *.MP3; do split.exe --bytes=2500k -d "$file" "$file"; done
```

produces the files **01_dickens_copperfield.mp301**, **01_dickens_copperfield.mp302**, **01_dickens_copperfield.mp303**, and so on. Next, doing

```
for file in *.*; do mv "$file" "$file".mp3; done
```

gives: 01_dickens-copperfield.mp301.mp3, 01_dickens_copperfield.mp302.mp3, *.mp3ac.mp3 and so on.

How do I tell it to split the file into files having the original name but not the extension. Let `mv` add extention.
Sorry for such lenghty expose. I am learning my way into this beautiful jungle but full of powerful animals such as these split, mv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you use Linux and GNU `split`. If so, you can do this directly with `split`.

So, how does `split` work? As with most *nix software, its manual is available by running `man split`. Specifically, the general usage is

```
split [OPTION]... [INPUT [PREFIX]]
```

That means that you can specify the prefix yourself. For example, if you split a file called `foo` and give the prefix bar:

```
$ ls
foo
$ split foo bar
$ ls
baraa  barab  barac  foo
```

As you can see, since a prefix was given to `split`, it has created the files called `bar` followed by a suffix (`aa` to `ac` in this case). So, in your case, you want to give the name of the file as a prefix:

```
for f in *mp3; do split "$f" "$f"
```

But you also want to remove the extension so that splitting `foo.mp3` does not result in `foo.mp3aa` but `fooaa`. This can be done using bash's string manipulation [capabilities](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) by writing `${f%.mp3}` instead of simple `$f`.

Finally, you can use another nifty feature of `split` to add the extension:

```
   --additional-suffix=SUFFIX
          append an additional SUFFIX to file names.
```

So, putting it all together:

```
for f in *mp3; do 
   split --bytes=2500k --additional-suffix=".mp3" -d "$f" "${f%.mp3}_"; 
done
```

I ran this in a directory that contained the following files:

```
aa.mp3  bb.mp3  cc.mp3
```

And it resulted in these split file names:

```
aa_00.mp3  aa_02.mp3  bb_00.mp3  bb_02.mp3  cc_00.mp3  cc_02.mp3
aa_01.mp3  aa_03.mp3  bb_01.mp3  bb_03.mp3  cc_01.mp3  cc_03.mp3
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for:         **the stripping capabilities .... ${f%.mp3}**. As @peterph noted I was sadly using the commands in cygwin on windows and there split binary strangely enough didn't support **--additional-suffix** argument. Tested on linux and it works.

Answer (score 2):

First, your loop seems to be semantically flawed - it certainly doesn't recreate the original file. What it does is renaming the files. While this will usually work (at least to some extent) with some simply structured data (which MP3s actually are), it will become unusable with most other kinds of data (images and often video for example). Naming the resulting files with the same extension is thus highly unrecommendable - it is rather misleading, since the resulting files are not what the extension would suggest. While on UNIX one can always use the `file` utility to check what the content of a file is, once you start working with the data on Windows (which your `split.exe` suggests), you'll realize that that it is a bit suboptimal.

To recreate the original, you would need:

```
> recreated_original.mp3
for f in *0?; do
   cat "$f" >> recreated_original.mp3
done
```

or simply use shell wild-card expansion:

```
cat *0? > recreated_original.mp3
```

This will of course overwrite `recreated_original.mp3`, if it already exists.

If, for some reason, you really want to keep the original extension after the chunk number, your loop is a good way to achieve this. If you happen to be using `split` from GNU Coreutils, you can use its `--additional-suffix` option:

```
split --bytes=2300k -d --additional-suffix=.mp3 01_somefile.mp3 01_somefile.mp3.
```

Note the trailing dot in the `PREFIX` argument - this ensures that the names will look like this:

```
01_somefile.mp3.00.mp3
01_somefile.mp3.01.mp3
...
```

You might want to make the chunk numbers longer by using the `-a` option, so that you can split the files into more smaller parts (while `-a 2` - which is the default - is often not enough, value of 3 or 4 is ok in most cases).

In case you needed to work with chunks of different files separately, you can do it for example in nested loop:

```
for base in *.00; do
    base=${base%.??}
    for file in $base*; do
        # your stuff goes here
    done
done
```

`${base%.??}` returns the content of variable `base` with the trailing dot and two arbitrary characters removed - thus it becomes the base name of the first chunk. Remember to remove the dot if you use your original chunk naming and to adjust the number of characters used for chunk naming.

Comment: I don't think the OP is trying to recreate the original. They just want each fragment to have the extension `.mp3`.

Comment: @terdon might be, but it really is not a good idea.

Comment: @peterph yes I am not trying to recreate the original, but what you 've put in your answer obliges me to further inquiry and practice.As terdon  already showed in his answer, I am able to split one mp3 into others and they work as mp3 really well(well, its about audiobooks that I find large, the resulting pieces flow one after another quite nicely)

Answer (score 2):

When you do the split, use `basename` to strip the `.MP3` to create the stem you require.

```
for file in *.MP3; do split.exe --bytes=2500k -d "$file" `basename "$file" .MP3`; done
```

Now your second loop should do as you want.

Comment: @terdon: From a [basename(1)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/basename.html) manpage: 'the suffix string suffix, if present, shall be removed.' The invocation of `basename` in this answer includes a suffix string.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman ah, I stand corrected, thank you. X Tian, my apologies, clearly I should have checked before commenting. Downvote removed, upvote added.

Comment: @X Tian, the command didn't work it gives a bunch of      split: basename "$file" .mp300: invalid argument

Comment: @innn Hmm, only reason I could imagine is if the back-quotes were omitted, split should not see the word basename. (@terdon I missed your edit and down-vote, but apologies accepted, tks)